# Override Librarys using Modeler, Rigger, Animator Workflow in seperate blend files

Tags: workflow, library-overrides

I am trying to use a specific workflow with three .blend files.

The first file  (modeler.blend) contains the modeling, materials, and textures. The model is in a collection.

The second file (rigger.blend) contains the rig with a link and an override of the collection of the model from the "modeler.blend" file. For simplicity, the model is parented (skinned) with  automatic weights. The linked and overridden model now has vertex groups as the result of the skinning. For simplicity, I add one Shape Key. The rig now moves the mesh as expected. The rig and linked (overridden) model are in a hierarchy of collections with the rig at the base and the model higher in the tree.

The third file (animator.blend) links (and overrides) the collection from rigger.blend that contains the rig and model. This is where things breakdown. The model/mesh will not move when the rig is posed.

This case seems in line with multiple creators working together to complete a project. I must be doing something wrong. I expect mesh to move when I pose the rig for animating in the animator file.

I guess the linked/overridden model/mesh cannot be linked into yet another file and overridden again?

If I link and override just the rig from "rigger" file and the model from the "modeler" file into the "animator" file, the model will not have the vertex groups and the Key Shape from the "rigger" file.

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong please let me know.

I am trying to (loosely) follow the workflow from this post https://download.blender.org/institute/nodes-design/pipeline.html

Thanks.